# Centering Modal (Twitter Bootstrap)

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

So I'm making a website using ASP.NET MVC and I'm having trouble with the modal that I make. Before I already used a modal and it's working properly, it's popping up in the middle. But now when I tried to put a modal in the new website that I'm making the modal appears on the right side, you can only see the 1/8 of it. But if your going to restore down the browser you can see it perfectly. I really don't know why this is happening. I hope someone can help me. Thank you in advance. Here's the .cshtml code:

This is where I call the modal:

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 p-1 animated umScaleIn">
    <div class="project-item">
        <img src="~/Content/mytemplate/img/mucisian/5SOS.jpg" />
        <div class="overlay">
            <h4><a href="#5SOSModal" data-toggle="modal" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">5 Seconds of Summer</a></h4>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And this is the modal:

```
<div id="5SOSModal" class="modal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">

            <div class="modal-header">
                <button data-dismiss="modal" class="close"><span>&times;</span></button>
                <h3 class="modal-title"> 5 Seconds of Summer </h3>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-body">
                <figure>
                    <img src="~/Content/mytemplate/img/mucisian/5SOS.jpg" />
                </figure>
                <div class="offer-content text-center">
                    <h4>5SOS 5SOS</h4>
                    <p>Sed sagittis nunc vel tellus ultricies auctor. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia , per inceptos himenaeos. Integer eleifend tellu.</p>
                    <span class="offer-left"><i></i></span>
                    <span class="offer-right"><i></i></span>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-footer">
                <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" class="shortcode_button">Exit</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the CSS of the Modal:

```
.modal {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1040;
  display: none;
  overflow: auto;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.modal-dialog {
  z-index: 1050;
  width: auto;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

[image: This is what it looks like when the browser's @100%]

Comment: Try add the website link

Comment: I have try with your code and it is working fine  ,see https://jsfiddle.net/j8vt6981/6/ , there must be other css which is affecting the model popup